# Windows XP Service Pack 3 installs unknown devices

Tags: windows, windows-xp, drivers, sp3

The other day I decided to rebuild the software on my PC. starting with Windows XP, I did a fresh install, and proceeded to install all of the drivers until there were no "Unknown Devices" in the device manager.

Then I installed Service Pack 3, and all of a sudden, I have 4 unknown instances of:

> "Audio Device on High Definition Audio Bus"

Why would these only show up after an install of Service Pack 3?

...this seems very odd!

Comment: Was Service Pack 3 the only update?

Comment: They would show up if the drivers were removed because the update was installed.  Just install the drivers for this device.

Comment: @Ramhound, I don't know what the device is. My O/B sound card is disabled. I have an Alesis IO|26 FireWire production card and an X-Fi Titanium, but all drivers for those are present and correct! - Could it be to do with HDMI sound via my graphics card, maybe?

Comment: @series0ne - I don't know what hardware you have on your system.  If everything is working, then a couple unknown devices, isn't really a problem.

Comment: @Ramhound, Ah you would think so! But ever since installing SP3, I'm getting BSOD's with ever other boot. The machine really isn't suited to XP but I need it for some legacy applications. I might consider moving to Windows 7 32-bit though.

Comment: @series0ne - If you want help post the information with regards to BSOD.  I still maintain you should be able to install generic drivers for these devices.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Look up the Hardware ids on the internet for the devices to see what they are. One good place is the [PCI Database.com](http://www.pcidatabase.com/) or just Google the strings.

[image]